# How to access a python script with python-shell in a sails.js App?

Tags: python, node.js, sails.js, child-process

I want to access a python script and pass an image then wait for a json response . I should do this inside the "upload" function after getting the image.

Been searching but was not able to find a python-shell with sails. Since sails is built on top of node.js then there most be a way.

```
module.exports = {

fileUpload: function(req, res) {

        res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/html' });
        res.end(
            '<form action="http://localhost:1337/postIts/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">' +
            '<input type="text" name="title"><br>' +
            '<input type="file" name="uploadFile"><br>' +
            '<input type="submit" value="Upload">' +
            '</form>'
        )
    },
    upload: function(req, res) {
        var uploadFile = req.file('uploadFile')

        uploadFile.upload({
            saveAs: 'image.png'
        }, function onUploadComplete(err, files) {
            if (err)
                return res.serverError(err);
            return res.json({
                message: files.length + ' file(s) uploaded successfully!',
                files: files[0]
            });
        });
    }
};
```

I want to pass this uploaded image to python script and wait for a json output which I will return to the client. I havent tried anything because I am not sure of the proper way of doing this.

It should be something similar to this but i dont know the proper way. of doing it in my Controller.

there should be an import python-shell somewhere, maybe before the module.export ?

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

var courseid=req.param('courseid');

sails.log.debug(coursed);

var options = {
args: [courseid]
};

PythonShell.run('word2vec.py', options, function (err, results) {

if (err) throw err;

console.log('results: %s', results[0]);

});

return res.ok();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I have tried installing pythonshell then tried an import from the controller and add the codes to the upload function which calls for the .py script but I get an error, I will upload a picture of the error. And here is the new code:

```
import { PythonShell } from 'python-shell';
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

module.exports = {                                                                                  
   upload: function(req, res) {
        var uploadFile = req.file('uploadFile')

        uploadFile.upload({
            saveAs: 'image.png',
        }, function onUploadComplete(err, files) {

            let options = {
                mode: 'text',
                pythonOptions: ['-u'], // get print results in real-time
                scriptPath: sails.config.pythonPath,
                args: ['1233ID', files[0].fd]
            };

            PythonShell.run('main2.py', options, function(err, results) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('results: %s', results);
            });

            if (err)
                return res.serverError(err);

            return res.json({
                message: files.length + ' file(s) uploaded successfully!',
                files: files[0].fd
            });
        });
    }
};
```

[see the screenshot for the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNaZf.png)

Comment: I made it work by removing the `import` and changing the `var PythonShell` to `let {PythonsShell`.